# Htaccess. How priority RewriteRule over RewriteRule index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added [L] but apache always run index.php first. Anyway can fix this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore */*
ErrorDocument 404   "error404"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule   ^/([0-9]+)WEB([0-9]+)$  /order?c=$1WEB$2 [L] <- i want run this first

RewriteRule . index.php <- apache always run this
```

Comment: This is due to the leading slash in your firstRule's pattern. Apache ignores it. Remove the slash and you will be fine.

Comment: its still not working :(